# MongoDB lists - get every Nth item

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a Mongodb schema that looks roughly like:

```
[
  {
    "name" : "name1",
    "instances" : [ 
      {
        "value" : 1,
        "date" : ISODate("2015-03-04T00:00:00.000Z")            
      }, 
      {
        "value" : 2,
        "date" : ISODate("2015-04-01T00:00:00.000Z")
      }, 
      {
        "value" : 2.5,
        "date" : ISODate("2015-03-05T00:00:00.000Z")
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  {
    "name" : "name2",
    "instances" : [ 
      ...
    ]
  }
]
```

where the number of instances for each element can be quite big.

I sometimes want to get only a sample of the data, that is, get every 3rd instance, or every 10th instance... you get the picture.

I can achieve this goal by getting all instances and filtering them in my server code, but I was wondering if there's a way to do it by using some aggregation query.

Any ideas?

---

**Updated**

Assuming the data structure was flat as @SylvainLeroux suggested below, that is:

```
[
  {"name": "name1", "value": 1, "date": ISODate("2015-03-04T00:00:00.000Z")},
  {"name": "name2", "value": 5, "date": ISODate("2015-04-04T00:00:00.000Z")},
  {"name": "name1", "value": 2, "date": ISODate("2015-04-01T00:00:00.000Z")},
  {"name": "name1", "value": 2.5, "date": ISODate("2015-03-05T00:00:00.000Z")},
  ...
]
```

will the task of getting every Nth item (of specific `name`) be easier?

Comment: FWIW: _"the number of instances for each element can be quite big."_ Maybe using an embedded document here is not a good idea, if the number of document is so big that it could finally reach the 32MB limit. In addition, if you regularly have to access a subset of that "big" array, maybe it is an other clue the schema is not appropriate. Without knowing your exact needs, I would have think of something more like `{  "name" : "name1", value: 1, date: ... }, {  "name" : "name1", value: 2, date: ... }, ...` With that schema, you could even (ab)use the _id field to pick a *biased* data sample.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux, instances share more than just a name (I simplified the schema for this question's purpose). I don't want every instance to contain basically the same data as others, so I have a parent object with multiple instances. Made more sense to me that way. But I'm open to suggestions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might like this approach using the [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation. And probably the most convenient and fastest way without any aggregation trick.

Create a collection **`Names`** with the following schema

```
[
  { "_id": 1, "name": "name1" },
  { "_id": 2, "name": "name2" }
]
```

and then **`Instances`** collection having the parent id as `"nameId"`

```
[
  { "nameId": 1, "value" : 1, "date" : ISODate("2015-03-04T00:00:00.000Z") },
  { "nameId": 1, "value" : 2, "date" : ISODate("2015-04-01T00:00:00.000Z") },
  { "nameId": 1, "value" : 3, "date" : ISODate("2015-03-05T00:00:00.000Z") },
  { "nameId": 2, "value" : 7, "date" : ISODate("2015-03-04T00:00:00.000Z") }, 
  { "nameId": 2, "value" : 8, "date" : ISODate("2015-04-01T00:00:00.000Z") }, 
  { "nameId": 2, "value" : 4, "date" : ISODate("2015-03-05T00:00:00.000Z") }
]
```

Now with [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation **3.6** syntax you can use [**`$sample`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) inside the [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) [**`pipeline`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup) to get the every **Nth** element randomly.

```
db.Names.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Instances.collection.name,
    "let": { "nameId": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$nameId", "$$nameId"] }}},
      { "$sample": { "size": N }}
    ],
    "as": "instances"
  }}
])
```

You can test it [**here**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bfQ0C4MUG5k)

Comment: $sample - Randomly selects the specified number of documents from its input. I don't think the question talks about random sampling.

Comment: YvanPearson If the OP needs specific element from the array then other aggregation operators like `$arrayElemAt` , `$slice` would work here. But it is not requirement here. OP needs random element.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that your question clearly asked "get every nth instance" which does seem like a pretty clear question.

Query operations like `.find()` can really only return the document "as is" with the exception of general field "selection" in projection and operators such as the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) match operator or [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) that allow a singular matched array element.

Of course there is [**`$slice`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/), but that just allows a "range selection" on the array, so again does not apply.

The "only" things that can modify a result on the server are [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) and [`.mapReduce()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/). The former does not "play very well" with "slicing" arrays in any way, at least not by "n" elements. However since the "function()" arguments of mapReduce are JavaScript based logic, then you have a little more room to play with.

For analytical processes, and for analytical purposes "only" then just filter the array contents via mapReduce using [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {
        var id = this._id;
        delete this._id;

        // filter the content of "instances" to every 3rd item only
        this.instances = this.instances.filter(function(el,idx) {
            return ((idx+1) % 3) == 0;
        });
        emit(id,this);
    },
    function() {},
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } } // or output to collection as required
)
```

It's really just a "JavaScript runner" at this point, but if this is just for anaylsis/testing then there is nothing generally wrong with the concept. Of course the output is not "exactly" how your document is structured, but it's as near a facsimile as mapReduce can get.

The other suggestion I see here requires creating a new collection with all the items "denormalized" and inserting the "index" from the array as part of the unqique `_id` key. That may produce something you can query directly, bu for the "every nth item" you would still have to do:

```js
db.resultCollection.find({
     "_id.index": { "$in": [2,5,8,11,14] } // and so on ....
})
```

So work out and provide the index value of "every nth item" in order to get "every nth item". So that doesn't really seem to solve the problem that was asked.

If the output form seemed more desirable for your "testing" purposes, then a better subsequent query on those results would be using the aggregation pipeline, with [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)

```js
db.newCollection([
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": {
                "$eq": [ 
                    { "$mod": [ { "$add": [ "$_id.index", 1] }, 3 ] },
                0 ]
            },
            "then": "$$KEEP",
            "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }}
])
```

That at least uses a "logical condition" much the same as what was applied with `.filter()` before to just select the "nth index" items without listing all possible index values as a query argument.

Answer (score 5):

No [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) is needed here. You can use [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) with [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to project the array value at requested index inside [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) aggregation.

Something like

```
db.colname.aggregate(
[
  {"$group":{
    "_id":null,
    "valuesatNthindex":{"$push":{"$arrayElemAt":["$instances",N]}
    }}
  },
  {"$project":{"valuesatNthindex":1}}
])
```

Comment: Does this command require the entire collection to be loaded into memory?

Comment: @GabrielFair  Aggregation runs at server so nothing is loaded on the client side if that is what you are asking.

Comment: I think he's asking if the full collection needs to be loaded into the server's memory.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, with the aggregation framework it's not possible as this would require an option with **[`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)** to emit an array index/position, of which currently aggregation can't handle. There is an open JIRA ticket for this here **[SERVER-4588](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4588)**.

However, a workaround would be to use **[MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce)** but this comes at a huge performance cost since the actual calculations of getting the array index are performed using the embedded JavaScript engine (which is slow), and there still is a single global JavaScript lock, which only allows a single JavaScript thread to run at a single time.

With mapReduce, you could try something like this:

Mapping function:

```
var map = function(){
    for(var i=0; i < this.instances.length; i++){
        emit(
            { "_id": this._id,  "index": i },
            { "index": i, "value": this.instances[i] }
        );
    }
};
```

Reduce function:

```
var reduce = function(){}
```

You can then run the following **[`mapReduce`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/)** function on your collection:

```
db.collection.mapReduce( map, reduce, { out : "resultCollection" } );
```

And then you can query the result collection to geta list/array of every Nth item of the instance array by using the **[`map()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/)** cursor method :

```
var thirdInstances = db.resultCollection.find({"_id.index": N})
                                        .map(function(doc){return doc.value.value})
```

Comment: As you said, using MapReduce for ad-hoc queries has some performance penalties. However, depending the use case, if using stale data is acceptable, the OP could schedule a MapReduce job to run on regular basis in order to process some aggregate collection he could then query later.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Good call, absolutely agree.

Comment: The JIRA issue is now closed and fixed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            instances: {
                $map: {
                    input: { $range: [ 0, { $size: "$instances" }, N ] },
                    as: "index",
                    in: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$instances", "$$index" ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/index.html) generates a list of indexes. Third parameter represents **non-zero step**. For `N = 2` it will be `[0,2,4,6...]`, for `N = 3` it will return `[0,3,6,9...]` and so on. Then you can use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to get correspinding items from `instances` array.

Answer (score 2):

Or with just a find block:

```
db.Collection.find({}).then(function(data) {
  var ret = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 ) {
      ret.push(data[i]);
    }
  }
  return ret;
});
```

Returns a promise whose then() you can invoke to fetch the Nth modulo'ed data.

Comment: As you can see in my question, I already said that I can get all items and filter them in my code. My question was if there is a way to do it with a mongo query.