# How to reduce size of data sent from database?

Tags: database, mongodb

I want do reduce size of data I am receiving from mongoDB Atlas, hence speeding up waiting time.

I am using nodeRed as my back-end and I am retrieving power consumption data from database to show it in charts on front-end. I have tried to query database only for specific parameters like current and timestamp, hoping to reduce size of received data.

Collection consists of such documents:

```
{
_id:5d398ed7b4926101926e43bb
voltage:233.1302947998047
current:0.03415190055966377
fr:50.01874923706055
timestamp:2019-07-25T11:13:27.582+00:00
}
```

Query I have tried:

```
find({},{voltage:1, timestamp:1, _id:0})
```

I expect to make query which reduces data sent from DB on half or third by only sending every second or third document. Currently I am receiving all data for specific value and it takes around 2 min to receive everything.

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53811217/7076907 ?

Comment: This isn't Node-RED specific in any way. Also given the size of a full record choosing to not return the `current` or `fr` values will make little difference. I suggest you look to return just a given time period (records with `timestamp` between 2 values) rather than ALL the records.

Comment: Thank you @Rishav Agarwal, this looks like solution for me.